# Spring Boot Hyphenated Profile Names Work Inconsistently

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-config

Spring Boot profiles serviced from the cloud configuration server seem to support hyphens for application-specific properties files {application}-{profile}.properties, but not for the global properties files application-{profile}.properties

For example in an application named "testapp":

If the profile name is "testprofile" then placing properties in application-testprofile.properties and testapp-testprofile.properties will work. Verified using endpoint /testapp-testprofile.properties

If the profile name is "test-profile" however, properties in testapp-test-profile.properties will work, but application-test-profile.properties will not work. Verified using endpoint /testapp-test-profile.properties

Am I missing something, or is this a (very minor) bug/inconsistency in the way properties files are handled by the Spring cloud config server?

Using Spring Boot 1.5.0.RC1

Answer (score 0):

This is related to [this issue](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-config/issues/1069) which is still open to this day. Obviously the hyphen has a special meaning in the spring cloud config server HTTP service and there is no way to escape it. As others have done, I ended up not using hyphens in my profiles which is a bit annoying.